# Neo4j ExecutionEngine and ExecutionResult deprecated?

Tags: java, neo4j

In Neo4j's neo4j-2.2.0-M03 version, when I try to import

`import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine;` and

`import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionResult;`

I get a deprecated warning. I can't seem to find what packages I should use instead...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GraphDatabaseService` provides now a direct way to run a Cypher query using [`GraphDatabaseService.execute()`](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.0-M03/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html#execute(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map)). N.B. there are two variants of that method one with and one without parameters.

Answer (score 5):

Wow, I don't see any deprecation warnings, but using

```
ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(db, StringLogger.wrap(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out)));
ExecutionResult er = engine.execute(query);
```

gives me huge memory leak.
and this is completely ok

```
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = ...
Result er = graphDb.execute(query);
```